# How to get application logs running in container using loki

Tags: docker, kubernetes, grafana-loki

I understand that using loki (loki+promtail+grafana) we can get the logs from the containers and this logs location ususally /var/log. In my case I have an application running inside the container will generate logs which will be stored in the location available in the configuration. I need to trace these logs using loki server. I need to know how to add these application logs location in loki server config file along with container logs.

Comment: What is the application? If it is your custom code you can probably add a logging handler that would log to loki directly. Someting like [this](https://github.com/GreyZmeem/python-logging-loki) for python.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `/var/lib/docker/containers` you will see container IDs for each container. Mount this into `promtail` as a Docker volume.

`promtail` can scrape this using a config like:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: docker
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: docker
      __path__: /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log
```

The docker-compose volume block I use looks like:

```
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./promtail-config.yaml:/etc/promtail/docker-config.yaml
      - /var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/
```